# How to get the object using $.getJSON?

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, getjson

I want to parse json from local file by:

```
$.getJSON("test.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); 
});
```

But how to use object json in this case out of $.getJSON()?

For example, if the code is:

```
$.getJSON("test.json", function(json) {
    //console.log(json); 
});
console.log(json);
```

it will not show json in console. How to solve this?

I searched and tried as below:

```
                function getJsonData() {
                    $.getJSON("test.json", function (jsondata) {
                        callback(jsondata);
                    });
                }


                function callback(jsondata) {
                   //do something with the data
                    console.log(var1);
                    return var1;  //return the variable var1

                }


                var var1= getJsonData();
                console.log(var1);
```

But what's in the console is undefined.

Comment: The name of the parameter (`json`) is misleading. `.getJSON()` will pass the parsed response to the callback and not JSON.

Comment: But how to get the response from the callback? Could there be a simple example for this? Thanks very much.

Comment: Check the duplicate

Comment: I tried and re-edit the question.. encounter another problem, could you please help to fix it? It has confused me for a long time, thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed this issue.